# PowerShell script to update Task "Outcome" and "% Complete" fields

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, designer-workflow, task-list

I have a problem (see [Workflows do not continue after user completes a task nor do they update task outcome and percentage](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53937/workflows-do-not-continue-after-user-completes-a-task-nor-do-they-update-task-ou)) that I can't get around. I thought about running a powershell script every night to work around it.

It would look for all workflows in a site collection and if their Task Status is = "Completed" it will update the Outcome and also % Complete fields.

I'm hoping that 'unsticks' my workflows.

Can someone point me to a PowerShell script that would do this?

Comment: As an aside, I cannot see the "Outcome" field in the Task lists' Column settings.  I cannot use SPD to create a workaround script - one that would run on the Task list and if the Task Status = Completed to set Outcome = Completed. It doesn't "show" Outcome when I select the "Set Field" Action.

Comment: Are you using custom outcome field?

Answer (score 1):

you can try with following script,

```
 $list=$spweb.Lists["workflow list name"]
Foreach ($item in $list.Items) 
{
   $workflows = $item.workflows
   Foreach ($workflow in $workflows)
  {
    $tasks = $workflow.Tasks
    Foreach ($task in $tasks)
   {

    //Add your logic to update task property

    $task.Systemupdate()
}
}  
}
```

Comment: and...what would the logic BE to update the Outcome field? i'm not proficient in PowerShell and not a developer...I can run scripts if someone else writes them :)